# What maps have "Levolution"?

Tags: battlefield-1

In the newer Battlefield games, maps can be changed up by destroying a key part of the map (like skyscrapers or dams in Battlefield 4).

Although in Battlefield 1, they don't seem as.... common? there's no big skyscrapers to knock down, that's for sure.

Does each map have a levolution or are they only in a few maps?

I have found one in Sinai Desert where the archway can be toppled down and snipers then need to find a new favorite perch.

Comment: Not sure if this counts, but there is [small wooden bridge](https://youtu.be/vVeoHQwn0wk?t=19s) that can broken on Sinai Desert.  Besides that, whatever maps have a [giant Zeppelin Airship](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-yaSh-E8vo0), it looks like it can be shot down.  Where is lands (which is dynamic and not preset), mass destruction will occur, and the frame of the zeppelin will remain. I don't play BF1 and wasn't able to determine all the map names with the airships (I think one was Ballroom Blitz), but that's all I could find.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing similar to what you are talking about is the bridge on Sinai Desert between A and B, nothing else so far on the currents maps.

*Answering your question, only Sinai Desert has "Levolution"*

Answer (score 0):

With very few exceptions, every single building in the game, from small stone huts to larger brick houses and even windmills, can be severely damaged or destroyed. This makes attack and defence of different areas of the map an evolving conflict. Snipers pinning you down from the second floor of that windmill? Remove the second floor from the equation. Enemies bunkering down in that mansion? Blow some extra holes in the walls to breach from. Mortar crews taking cover in a compound? Flatten the walls of the compound, leaving nowhere to hide.

In terms of big changes to the map, there are a couple with bridges that can be destroyed, preventing vehicle access to some areas of the map. One in particular (can't remember the name but it's the one with a central fort) has a capture point in the centre of the map that can be completely cut off to vehicles by destroying a stone bridge.

There are also the behemoths of course; both the airship and armoured train will leave persistent wreckage where they are destroyed, which can aid or aggravate your assault. On maps where the armoured train travels through the centre very close to the control points, the burning wreckage can be useful for defence and a good pilot will make sure the train is in an advantageous position when it is destroyed.

Answer (score -1):

The destruction has always been in battlefield including buildings and the terrain. Levolution was introduced in Battlefield 3 while DICE was experimenting with their engine.

When the building falls in the map "Siege of Shanghai" in Battlefield 4, this event is called Levolution because it completely alters the area and also changes on the map. As far as I know they will be adding more soon.

Comment: "they are adding more soon" : do you have any source to that information?